# Adding labels to geom_col()

Tags: r, ggplot2

Working with the Pima Indians data set. I can get bar charts that show No and Yes for each of the numerical features (age, etc.). However, I'm not able to get the value to print clearly. It looks like blocks of color, not clear text.

I've played with the geom_text line every way I can think of to get clear labels, this is the best that is produced:

```
MASS::Pima.te %>%
  dplyr::mutate(dplyr::across(-type, as.numeric)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-type, names_to = "var", values_to = "value") %>%
  ggplot2::ggplot(aes(x = type, y = value)) +
  ggplot2::geom_col() +
  ggplot2::geom_text(aes(label = value), vjust = -2) +
  ggplot2::facet_wrap(~var, scales = "free") +
  ggplot2::labs(title = "Numerical values against y")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply summarize your data before passing it to `ggplot()` (`geom_col` will not that do that for you). As is you create a stacked bar chart of small bars for each observation and value in your data and hence get a label for each of these small bars which are placed on top of each other.

```r
MASS::Pima.te |>
  dplyr::mutate(dplyr::across(-type, as.numeric)) |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-type, names_to = "var", values_to = "value") |>
  dplyr::summarise(value = sum(value), .by = c(type, var)) |>
  ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x = type, y = value)) +
  ggplot2::geom_col() +
  ggplot2::geom_text(
    ggplot2::aes(label = value), vjust = -.2
  ) +
  ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0, .2, 0)) +
  ggplot2::facet_wrap(~var, scales = "free") +
  ggplot2::labs(title = "Numerical values against y")
```

[image]